# Error starting protocol stack: chaindata file exists

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to start geth from the terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I've already done it several times before, but now I'm getting the following error message:

```
INFO [08-21|12:34:05] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.6.7-stable-ab5646c5/linux-amd64/go1.8.1
INFO [08-21|12:34:05] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/home/titog/.ethereum/geth/chaindata cache=128 handles=1024
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: mkdir /home/titog/.ethereum/geth/chaindata: file exists
```

The chaindata is supposed to exist. How can I fix this issue and run geth?

My chaindata directory is a symbolic link to another directory in another disk, but this shouldn't be a problem because it worked before.

Comment: Hi there. What command are you using to start Geth?

Comment: Just "geth", with no arguments.